# Installed Windows 10 on Mac without using Boot Camp - Need Help About Right Click, Trackpad and Function Keys

Tags: windows-10, mac, touchpad, boot-camp, function-keys

I installed Windows 10 on Mac without using Boot Camp -

Actually all I need is Bootcamp menu, because you can activate right click and function keys with it. But I tried a lot of things from this forum and youtube videos but couldn't manage to use it. I installed Trackpad ++ but it's not functioning well, it randomly presses keys and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Boot Camp Windows support software separately.

You need a USB stick 16GB or larger, formatted to MS-DOS(FAT)
Run The Boot Camp Assistant from macOS
From the menu > Action > Download Windows Support Software
Choose your USB as the target.

Run the setup.exe from the USB when you're back in Windows.

More detail: Apple KB - [Download and install Windows support software on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204923)